# Grunt packages needs to be installed for every release branch of a project

Tags: tfs, gruntjs

We are using grunt for build automations. We have installed 5-6 corresponding packages for the project. We are using TFS as our source control management tool. Every time a branch is taken out for the release we have to install all the packages including grunt again and again. Windows 7 is our OS.

Is there any way to install grunt and related packages globally in Windows so that we don't have to do it again and again ?

Not sure if it would be related but we are using .NET for our development.

Comment: Are you using Nuget or npm?

Comment: I am using npm.. Nuget does not have all the grunt packages yet..